# Python KeyError while running script

Tags: python-3.3

I am running the below python script.

```
import cgi
import os
import time
import sys
import yate

print(yate.start_response('text/plain'))
addr=os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
host=os.environ['REMOTE_HOST']
method=os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD']
cur_time=time.asctime(time.localtime())
print(host+","+addr+","+cur_time+":"+method+":",end='',file=sys.stderr)
```

and i am getting the below error.

```
    addr=os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
  File "C:\Python33\lib\os.py", line 676, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'REMOTE_ADDR'
```

Please help on this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is supposed to be run as a [`CGI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) script by a web-server, which sets environment variables like `REMOTE_ADDR`, `REQUEST_METHOD`, etc.

You are running the script by yourself, and these environment variables are not available. That's why you get the `KeyError`.